# Display two entities into one table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

i have a custom table view cell. With two labels. 
The Label on the right loads its text from an entity. (See picture Below)

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
if (self.context == nil)
{
    self.context = [(RootAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
}
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];

[request setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
NSMutableArray *array = [[self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
[self setTableArray:array];
[self.myTableView reloadData];
[super viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

And i set the text accordingly as per documentation.

My problem lies when i try to load the second labels text from a different entity, So simply, i tried this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
if (self.context == nil)
{
    self.context = [(RootAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
}
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSFetchRequest *sRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
NSEntityDescription *sEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity2" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
[request setEntity:entity];
[sRequest setEntity:sEntity];
NSError *error;
NSError *sError;
NSMutableArray *array = [[self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *sArray = [[self.context executeFetchRequest:sRequest error:&sError]mutableCopy];
[self setTableArray:array];
[self setSecondTableArray:sArray];
[self.ammoTable reloadData];
[super viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

And i set the table View's cell's text via:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString * identifier = @"identifier";

self.cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

Entity2 *entity2 = [self.secondTableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Entity *entity = [self.tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

self.cell.rightLabel.text = [[entity.brand stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:entity.model];
self.cell.leftLabel.text = entity2.numberOfRounds;
return self.cell;
}
```

and i get this error, when i push this view:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM    objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'`

and i get a `SIGABRT` error on this line:

`Entity2 *entity2 = [self.secondTableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!
[image]

Comment: show entity2 in nslog , i think your entity2 look like empty.

Comment: self.secondTableArray  is Empty. you can make if condition as if ([self.secondTableArray  counts]){ self.cell.leftLabel.text = entity2.numberOfRounds;
} else { self.cell.leftLabel.text = @""; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to load 2 different entities, i just added another attribute to the original entity, and i imported/used the newly created attribute in the entity to populate the right label!